# SpriteKit linearDamping - maximum?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cocos2d-iphone

Note that Apple's doco asserts

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519796-lineardamping

> This property is used to simulate fluid or air friction forces on the body. The property must be a value between 0.0 **and 1.0**. The default value is 0.1. If the value is 0.0, no linear damping is applied to the object.

In fact: ***you can*** set values higher than one - so, "10.0" and "20.0" work perfectly; 1, 10 and 20 are all very clearly different.

- has anyone probed in to this and discovered if there is actually a maximum?  (If it just asymptotes away, what's the realistic range?)

Comment: linearDamping is velocity = velocity  / (1 + time * damping), so anything > than 1 would  be outside the scope of resistance during that frame.  This would mean that the damping effect would become sensitive to the time frame, and an inconsistency in frames could lead to inconsistent results,  which is what Box2D actually says about it. So the documents really should say it is strongly recommended, unless apple has placed a check in it to not allow the formula to use anything greater than 1 in the calculation

Comment: why would it be incorrect? if time is 1 and damping is .5  and velocity is 100 then 100 = 100 / (1 + 1 * 0.5), 100 = 100 / 1.5, so 66.666 would be your velocity after 1 second

Comment: it means you could end up where resistance could result in an effect that actually gives you speed

Comment: that is the formula Box2D uses,  which is the physics engine Physics Kit uses as its base

Comment: no, it is not based on a frame, it is based on the amount of time between frames

Comment: it is not the answer, you are concerned with why maximum of 10 being allowed in sprite kit,  I am telling you why Box2D allows for it it, I do not know if apple truncates the value to 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Apple doco is simply wrong.

Just to answer my own question, in iOS:

The actual documentation:

> This property is used to simulate fluid or air friction forces on the body. The property must be a value between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.1. If the value is 0.0, no linear damping is applied to the object.

is simply ***wrong***.

A value of about 10 to 15 is typical when you want typical "strong damping" like in many physics scenes.

I very often use values of 2 or 3.  And "10" is our value for "very thick honey".

Comment: Did you have issues with different devices, i.e., the same linear damping value had different effects between an iPad and an iPhone?

Comment: Glad I found this. I've been sticking to what the Apple docs say, and found that I couldn't achieve the effect I was looking for with values as detailed! Works a treat now.

Comment: what a hassle right ?!?  thanks, @VariableSquid